# How can I determine the process id (PID) of a WSL2 distro running in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I want to know how I can determine the process id (PID) of a launched WSL2 distro on Windows 10 using PowerShell?
After starting my default WSL2 distro using `wsl` command there are couple of WSL-related processes started on Windows:
[image: WSL2 related processes]

After that i used `Get-Process -Id` command to check details of each process where the IDs 6652 and 24500 seems to be most interesting.
The first process is related to `C:\WINDOWS\system32\wsl.exe` whereas the second ID points to the 'Store Version' of WSL2 under `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\MicrosoftCorporationII.WindowsSubsystemForLinux_1.2.5.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\wsl.exe`.

So I am not sure if WSL2 distros are generally listed as Windows processes?!